# Q&A site template like stackoverflow

Tags: php, templates, stack-overflow

I'm looking for a template for a Q&A site like stackoverflow preferably written in PHP. Does anybody knows any open-source template for that? I already searched github, but didn't find anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*

Comment: @HighCore Good, clear answer (thank you for that +1) but I've never understood that line of thinking. It's a bit like saying there's no point answering coding questions because most problems can be solved with a variety of methods and tools, and it's a matter of opinion. The spam part I get, but there must be other ways to control that aspect than throwing the baby out with the bath water.

Comment: Mohammed S posted this and then withdrew his answer, but I found the information helpful: [http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think both of these are open-source and PHP.

http://www.question2answer.org/qa/

http://support.lampcms.com/